# SQL - openjson to extract key from json

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql, parsing

Below `@json` contains 3 data object within an array. After using `OPENJSON` to extract these objects to a Table variable, please see the output attached.

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX);  
SET @json = N'[{"Container":"MSKU2913236","Seal":"ML-TH4773979","Size":"20","Temperature":"-20","TareWeight":"3.132","CreatedDate":"02-02-2018 00:00:00","Comment":null,"NetWeight":"21.445","TempRec#":null},{"Container":"MSKU3432702","Seal":"ML-TH4773972","Size":"20","Temperature":"-40","TareWeight":"2.872","CreatedDate":"02-02-2018 00:00:00","Comment":null,"NetWeight":"23.932","TempRec#":"TR12345"},{"Container":"MSKU4043053","Seal":"ML-TH4773973","Size":"20","Temperature":"-20","TareWeight":"2.995","CreatedDate":"02-02-2018 00:00:00","Comment":null,"NetWeight":"22.4","TempRec#":null}]';

DECLARE @ContainerTable TABLE(
    [Key] NVARCHAR(100),
    [Data] NVARCHAR(MAX)
);

INSERT INTO @ContainerTable
SELECT [key], [value] FROM OPENJSON(@json)

SELECT * FROM @ContainerTable
```

**Output**

[image]

Objective is to replace the `Key` column values with the `Container` property value from json in the `Data` column for all 3 rows.

**Expected Output**

[image]

Note: Expected output is hard coded and it only shows the one row but same is required for all rows.

Comment: Resultset is not json, I am storing data in table and need to replace key with one of the property value of the json

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `JSON_VALUE`:

```
INSERT INTO @ContainerTable([Key], [Data])
SELECT JSON_VALUE([value],'$.Container'), [value]
FROM OPENJSON(@json);
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5536cf2e25567088b9d37eab07d9096c)**

Comment: No need for the sub-select, this `SELECT JSON_VALUE([value],'$.Container'), [value] 
FROM OPENJSON(@json)` is enough...